# Function variable added to global scope

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I declared the function:

```
function makePerson() {
    this.first = 'John';
    this.last = 'Oliver';
    fullName = function(){
        return this.first + this.last;
    }
}
```

Did not instantiate it but called this function.

```
makePerson()
```

Now I am able to access `first`, `last` and `fullName` in global access.

Can someone explain me why it happens.

Note: Rather than calling, I instantiated it and checked. It is not in global and is accessible within function/class/object scope.

Comment: you should go through this http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: Because `fullName`, as you declared it, is a global function.

Comment: in your case `this === window` so, `this.first = 'John'` equals to `window.first = 'John'` and equals to `var first = 'John'`. That is because you call your class as function. Use it as constructor `var person = new makePerson()`, and after this you can access to `person.first`. Also, change `fullName` to `this.fullName`

Comment: @UmidbekKarimov thanks. ur replu and the answer below explained the concept pretty well.

Comment: Maybe the following answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Comment: @HMR Thanks for that wonderful link. That explains a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the normal semantics of the `this` keyword in a function. `this` may be evaluated in several ways, depending on how you call the function. Let's say we have the function `f` which body contains the `this` keyword :

1. In `f(a,b)` (standard function call syntax) `this` is bound to the global JavaScript `Object`, which means that if you add properties to `this` in the function body, you actually add them to global scope.
2. In `anObject.f(a,b)` (method call syntax), `this` is bound to `anObject`.
3. In `new f(a,b)` (constructor call syntax), `this` is bound to the object being constructed.

`this` can be a source of confusion, and as soon as a function body contains `this`, the function stops being first-class. For that reason, I recommend you to avoid using `this` as much as you can, [as does Douglas Crockford](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do?sortby=publicationDate).

If you want to make a factory function (which I strongly recommend for the reason above), you may do it that way :

```
function makePerson() {
    var person = {
        first: 'John',
        last: 'Oliver'
    };
    person.fullName = function(){
        return person.first + person.last;
    };
    return person;
}
```

If you still want to make a constructor, convention dictates that the name be capitalized :

```
function Person() {
    this.first = 'John';
    this.last = 'Oliver';
    this.fullName = function(){
        return this.first + this.last;
    };
}
```

Finally, there can be good reasons to use the `this` keyword, and that is prototypical inheritance. However, I find the constructor syntax to be misleading in that regard. Fortunately, now we have [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
var personPrototype = {
    fullName: function () {
        return this.first + this.last;
    }
};
function makePerson(first,last) {
    var person = Object.create(personPrototype);
    person.first = first;
    person.last = last;
    return person;
}
```

As a last warning, here is an example of how using `this` can lead to unanticipated constraints and confusion :

```
var cn = makePerson("Chuck","Norris");
// works fine
console.log(cn.fullName());
// does not work, fullName is not a first-class function. You cannot detach it.
var fullName = cn.fullName;
console.log(fullName());
```